# Error processing SSI file - using IIS manager on windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, ssi

as the topic implies - I get the error (**error processing SSI file**) wherever I place my ssi code in html.
In order to enable server ssi I installed server side includes in Windows Features and used IIS Manager in Windows 7 to add new Module Mapping to a site.

The ssi files are in a seperate folder. I use the html include code: (it does not work) 
`<!--#include virtual="/includes/footer_content.ssi" -->`

If I place the ssi file in the root level and use the the html include code: (it works) 
`<!--#include file="footer_content.ssi" -->`

I would like to keep the ssi files in a seperate folder. Can anyone share some insite on a solution?

Also when I added new Module Mappings it looks like IIS added a config file to my root level with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SSI-html2" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use shtml files instead of files with suffix SSI. 
For example: `<!--#include virtual="/includes/footer.shtml" -->`
There can often be other conflicts that in turn will not allow the .shtml files to display correctly in IIS. To rule this out I would recommend testing a bit to a live server location and once you are confident your syntax and build is correct you can switch to your webserver and work through any issues, should there even be any.

Hope this helps and good luck